# Customer info (partner) in header | odoo 12

Tags: postgresql, report, odoo, odoo-12, qweb

I want to optimize the space and be a little more tidy.
For this I wanted to put in the header the info of the company and that of the client.
being the following provision:

LOGO | my company | partner

The part of the logo I have been able to dimension and that of my company it is easy because it will never change, I can write it by hand and it is always repeated, but the client part, I do not know how to complete it with "t-fields"

Anyone know a manual or give me a hand to know the fields I need.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you need header in three part so use given template.

```
<template id="custom_layout_header" inherit_id="report.external_layout_header">
    <div class="header" position="replace">
        <div class="header">
            <style>
                .bottom-bt{border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
            </style>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"  style="margin-top:25px;">
                    <img t-if="company.logo" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % company.logo" style="max-height: 45px;"/>
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <center><b>
                        <h3><span t-esc="company.name"/></h3>
                    </b>
                    <p>
                        <span t-esc="company.street"/><span t-esc="company.street2"/>
                        <br/><span t-esc="company.city"/>,<span t-esc="company.zip"/>,<span t-esc="company.state_id.name"/>,<span t-esc="company.country_id.name"/>
                    </p></center>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <span t-field="company.rml_header1"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <p class="text-left">your partnerfields<span t-esc="yourpartnerfield"/></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row zero_min_height">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="bottom-bt"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: hi @saumil
i try to modify thw view: external_layout_clean

and this view modify my field that i want.

it right i do?

or need create a new template and link my report that i use (report_invoice_document_inherit).

Comment: See @Dani , in your you have header class right?,  Remove that div and call this template for header part it will gives you Logo | My company | partner(you must replace partner field in the given template)., Is that what you want?